# Как пересобрать request в django?

Tags: django, request

Есть объект request класса `<class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>`. 
Он выглядит так (могут быть разные значения параметров):

```
 <WSGIRequest: GET '/compare?type=all&type1=transit>
```

Я получаю его в функцию и там же передаю его другой функции:

```
def compareStats(request):
    ...
    data1 = get_stats(request)
    ...
    data2 = get_stats(request)
```

То есть `get_stats` мне нужно вызвать два раза.
А вопрос такой: функцию `get_stats` я не могу изменить, а она принимает в качестве аргумента только type. Есть ли способ на основе полученного `request` создать новый `request`, в котором заменить значение `type` на значение `type1`?

**Update** по вопросу в комментариях.

В чём состоит задача: функция get_stats получает значения из базы данных в виде json-массива. Для этого в базу данных нужно отправить запрос, в который подставляются полученные из request значения. Что-то типа

```
sql = """ select data, attr  from record where type = {0}""".format(_type)
cursor.execute(sql)
value, attrs = cursor.fetchall()[0]
```

но запрос сложнее. На основе запроса возвращается

```
return JsonResponse({'data': response})
```

В двух разных вызовах `get_stats` должны передаться разные параметры (но объект `request` изначально один, вот в чём проблема для меня) и должны получиться разные результаты.
Другое решение есть - немного изменить логику `get_stats`, вместо `get_stats` использовать другую функцию. Это решение уже применено и работает. Но мне кажется, что логичнее и проще переопределить объект `request`, который передаётся в качестве параметра в функцию `get_stats`, если это возможно.

И поэтому вопрос именно такой - можно ли сделать новый `request` на основе полученного? Будет ли это правильно и хорошо? Если нет, то как правильно и хорошо поступить в моём случае?

Comment: Прошу прощения за любопытство. А зачем оно вообще надо?

Comment: @МистерФикс , data1 должна быть основана на значении type, а data2 - на type1. Одна логика получения данных, но 2 разных значения. Изначально нужна была только data1, но по ходу развития пришлось использовать такой вот костыль.

Comment: Можно в принципе в любое время подменить значения, хоть в самом представлении. Непонятно в чём сложность. Непонятно зачем могло понадобиться. Никогда с таким не сталкивался.

Comment: @МистерФикс если опубликуете ответ, как передать в запрошенную `data2` функцию реквест с телом  `<WSGIRequest: GET '/compare?type=transit>`, буду благодарна. А то одним непонятно, в чём сложность, а другие не знают, как сделать.

Comment: Вы бы написали в чём состоит задача. Потому как есть подозрения, что может быть другое решение, более легальное.

Comment: Смотрю объект `HttpRequest` но не вижу там аттрибута `type`.

Comment: @МистерФикс def exportStats(request):        
    _type = request.GET.get('type', 'all')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> def exportStats(request): _type = request.GET.get('type', 'all')

атрибут request.GET - это просто словарь. Вы можете туда любые значения подставлять. В данном случае:

```
 request.GET['type'] = "моё значение"

def compareStats(request):
    data1 = get_stats(request)
    request.GET = {'type': "мои параметры", }
    data2 = get_stats(request)

def compareStats(request):
        data1 = get_stats(request)
        # чтобы сделать QueryDict изменяемым надо выполнить его метод copy()
        request.GET = request.GET.copy()
        request.GET['type'] = "Мои параметры"
        data2 = get_stats(request)
```

Если, конечно, нет возможности поправить интерфейс get_stats, то такой костыль наверное наиболее правильный.

Comment: `request.GET.get('type')`

Comment: `dict.get()` - это метод словаря.

Comment: По Вашему решению ошибка: `Exception Value: This QueryDict instance is immutable`

Comment: На самом деле есть возможность исправить get_stats. Правильнее именно так?

Comment: Я же не знаю, что у вас за код. Попробуйте просто подменить QueryDict джанговский на питонячий dict. Заменил решение.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста :)  .